# BreezeJS with ServiceStack?

Tags: servicestack, breeze, single-page-application

I was wondering whether or not BreezeJS is compatible when using other technologies other than Web API and/or Entity Framework? As I'm currently in development of a SPA using Service Stack to retrieve data and ORMLite?

So I am curious how BreezeJS handle's this as I know it uses it's own API Controller usually with an extension of the `DbContext` class which Entity Framework uses. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is currently a sample called NoDb in the samples zip available on the breeze website. This sample does not use EF, but it does use WebApi.  So I'd start by looking there. ( additional documentation on this sample should be added within a day or two as well).

In terms of using ServiceStack instead of WebApi, breeze supports the concept of a "dataServiceAdapter" and currently ships with two, an OData adapter and a WebApi adapter. It is certainly possible to write a ServiceStack adapter that breeze could use but this is not trivial.  Please add this as a feature request ( and vote for it) on the breeze [User Voice](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions).  We take these requests seriously.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link! I've made a request: https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions/suggestions/3567660-provide-a-servicestack-adapter . I will also take a look at the sample for NoDb!